# LLBGen for dummies

Tags: c#, sql, .net, llblgen

I have an "opportunity" to work with LLBLGEN ORM, I have already spent two days on trying to query a JOIN command over several tables (without any success). Now at home I also trying to understand the logic of this ORM on smaller project (ie. Recruiter->JobOffer->Candidate).
And yet this piece of software is whooping my ass. So I went to the documentation and tried to get some knowledge from with, unfortunately without any success.

So I'm asking here, is there somewhere a tutorial for real dummies that easily explains the very fundamental usage of LLBLGEN :

- where (ok, I've got this covered already)
- join
- multi join

Maybe someone has some code and db, that can share and illustrates this concepts done in friendly way.

Thanks!

Comment: The forums and support for LLBL are excellent, so if you have specific questions, ask there.  Also, if you are dealing with prefetch paths, read this excellent article (not by me):  http://www.llblgening.com/archive/2009/10/prefetchpaths-in-depth/

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think its the best and the closest thing I was looking for.

Comment: I'm actually just writing up a short, hands-on, easy to understand series of blog posts which covers the most common filtering and prefetching scenarios. Might be useful to anyone looking for similar info as you did: http://cmikavac.net/tag/llblgen/

Answer (score 1):

Joins are expressed using a Relation object. If you want to retreive all Candidates of a specific Recruiter you could write something like this, asuming the tables have the correct Foreign Key relations

```
var list = new CandidateCollection();
var relationsToUse = new RelationCollection
{
  JobOfferEntity.Relations.CandidateEntityUsingCandidateId,
  RecruiterEntity.Relations.JobOfferEntityUsingJobOfferId
};
var filter = new PredicateExpression
{
  new FieldCompareValuePredicate(RecruiterFields.Id, ComparisonOperator.Equal, recruiterId)
};
list.GetMulti(filter, relationsToUse);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some central concepts in LLBLGen which I'll explain with samples in code and equivalent Sql query.

1. Predicate, IPredicate and PredicateExpression: These are translated to Where clauses. You can think of PredicateExpression as a complex predicate that's made of several predicates joined with AND and OR.

Note: Treat the code snippets below as pseudo code as I don't have access to LLBLGen right now.

```
    var pred = CustomerFields.Id == 5;
    new DataAccessAdapter.FetchEntityCollection(coll, new RelationPredicateBucket(pred));
```

This will roughly translate to:

```
  SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Id = 5
```

You can combine several predicates using PredicateExpression:

```
   var predEx = new PredicateExpression();
   predEx.Add(CustomerFields.Id == 5);
   predEx.AddWithOr(CustomerFields.Name == "X");
```

Is equivalent to:

```
   SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Id = 5 OR Name = 'X'
```

2. Relations: Relations represents the relations in your database. There's a Relations property in every Entity in generated code that contains every relation of that entity. For example if you have a Customer table that has a one-to-many relation with your Order table, the corresponding Entities will have a static Relations property that contains those relations:

   CustomerEntity.Relations.OrderEntityUsingCustomerId;
   OrderEntity.Relations.CustomerEntityUsingCustomerId;

You use these relations when you want to perform a join and return results based on the join. For example if you want to fetch all customers that have an order that's varlue is greater than 50000 you do this:

```
var pred = OrderFields.Value > 50000;
var rpb = new RelationPredicateBucket();
rpb.PredicateExpression.Add(pred);
rpb.Relations.Add(CustomerEntity.Relations.OrderEntityUsingCustomerId);//perform join
```

This will translate to:

```
SELECT C.* FROM Customer AS C JOIN Order AS O ON C.Id = O.CustomerId WHERE O.Value > 50000
```

For multiple joins you just add more relations, to get customer that have orders with values higher than 50000 that have an OrderDetail that's quantity is more than 1:

```
var pred = OrderFields.Value > 50000 & OrderDetailFields.Quantity > 1;
var rpb = new RelationPredicateBucket();
rpb.PredicateExpression.Add(pred);
rpb.Relations.Add(CustomerEntity.Relations.OrderEntityUsingCustomerId);//perform customer and order join
rpb.Relations.Add(OrderEntity.Relations.OrderDetailEntityUsingOrderId);//perform order and order detail join
```

Which produces this sql query:

```
SELECT C.* FROM Customer AS C JOIN Order AS O ON C.Id = O.CustomerId JOIN OrderDetail AS OD ON OD.OrderId = O.Id WHERE O.Value > 50000 AND OD.Quantity > 1
```